# Filling missing date (day) values with 0

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe:

```
     day  Datavalue
    2020-06-01   3.179695
    2020-06-02   0.132487
    2020-06-08   3.179695
    2020-06-09   3.179695
    2020-06-10   3.179695
```

I would like to set a date range and add any dates that aren't in the dataframe as 0 for example:

```
     day  Datavalue
    2020-06-01   3.179695
    2020-06-02   0.132487
    2020-06-03   0
    2020-06-04   0
    2020-06-05   0
    2020-06-06   0
    2020-06-07   0
    2020-06-08   3.179695
    2020-06-09   3.179695
    2020-06-10   3.179695
```

I have tried

```
      mydates = pd.period_range(date - timedelta(40), date + timedelta(40)
      x = data.set_index('day') 
      x = data.reindex(mydates, fill_value=0)
```

but this just sets it all to zeros

[image: y]

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is to be done for the entire DataFrame, use `asfreq`:

```
df.set_index('day').asfreq('1D', fill_value=0)

            Datavalue
day                  
2020-06-01   3.179695
2020-06-02   0.132487
2020-06-03   0.000000
2020-06-04   0.000000
2020-06-05   0.000000
2020-06-06   0.000000
2020-06-07   0.000000
2020-06-08   3.179695
2020-06-09   3.179695
2020-06-10   3.179695
```

Comment: would `df.set_index('day').resample('1D').sum()` work here ?

Comment: @Datanovice good idea, but `resample` groups data (and is more suited for downsampling). `asfreq` is a similar method but faster and more suited to this task, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
delta = 2 # number of days before first value and after last value (as it seems to be needed from your code)

mydates = pd.period_range(df.date.iloc[0] - timedelta(delta), df.date.iloc[-1] + timedelta(delta))

# Change PeriodIndex object to datetime type:
mydates = mydates.to_timestamp() 

# Create dates dataframe and merge with original df containing values
dates_df = pd.DataFrame(mydates, columns=['date'])
new_df= pd.merge(df, dates_df, on='date', how='outer').sort_values('date').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, for putting me in the right direction, as I wanted to also extend the range a number of days prior and after the timeseries. I ended up using `new_df = pd.merge(df, dates_df, on='day', how='right').fillna(0)`   , which seemed to work well, as the data in the original df were datatime objects I converted the dates in dates_df to datetime objects too.